# Is it possible to include (but not importing) a stand-alone grammar in ANTLR4?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I have a grammar which describes expressions (original, right?).  I want to use this Expressions language inside of other languages.

For example, OtherLanguage.g4:

```
grammar OtherLanguage.g4

import Expressions;

keyPair: IDENTIFIER ':' expression;
IDENTIFIER: [a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

If I use `import Expressions;`, then it generates a valid parser, but it doesn't generate or use `ExpressionsParser.ExpressionContext`, but instead generates and uses `OtherLanguageParser.ExpressionContext`.  This means I can't create methods that take in "ExpressionContext" and reuse them in other projects.

Is there a feature of ANTLR4 that will make this work?

In other words, I don't want to "import" the Expressions grammar, but the parser and lexer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, import really means include---it is not treating the imported grammar as a separate entity for which you can use all of those parts tree objects.

Comment: Yes, my question is, is there a way to treat the tree as separate entities?

Comment: Terence's (implied) answer is most probably: no there is no way to do so, and _yeah, import really means include ..._

Comment: Sounds like I'd have to do some code-generation magic to achieve what I want.  Luckily there is StringTemplate and antlr ;-) Thanks @terence-parr